# send a variable to nginx and take it back

Tags: variables, nginx

I am sending custom variables to nginx like this:

```
http://myserver2.com/adm/306/89/protectedfile.zip?h=4JljxlK530mM6CPbG5wdTQ&e=1372125364&o=279
```

the variables "h" and "e" are for the secure_link mod, the "o" was added by me and is the one I want to take back in post_action. See my directives:

```
    location /adm/ {
        secure_link $arg_h,$arg_e;
        secure_link_md5 SECRETKEY$uri$arg_e$remote_addr;
        if ($secure_link = "") {
            return 403;
        }
        if ($secure_link = "0") {
            return 403;
        }
        rewrite  ^/adm/(.*)$  /download/$1  break;
        post_action /has_finished_downloading/$1;
    }

    location /has_finished_downloading/ {
        resolver 8.8.8.8;
        proxy_pass http://mymainserver.com/download_complete.php?ip=$remote_addr&body_bytes_sent=$body_bytes_sent&status=$request_completion&file_name=$1;
    }
```

This way, I can take back some variables successfully, including for example $_GET['file_name'] which is "/adm/306/89/protectedfile.zip".
Except the "o" variable. I tried many things to take back the $_GET['o] without success in my php script. It is not sent by nginx, and I have no ideas left how to do it the correct way.

I also tried this but it fails (adding $arg_o):

```
location /has_finished_downloading/ {
    resolver 8.8.8.8;
    proxy_pass http://mymainserver.com/download_complete.php?ip=$remote_addr&body_bytes_sent=$body_bytes_sent&status=$request_completion&file_name=$1&myo=$arg_o;
}
```

Thank you for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I more or less solved it with

```
$request_uri
```